# Generalizing XSLT code

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-1.0, generalization

I'm trying to learn the different possibilities to generalize XSLT templates for the sake of reusing them at different places. So far, I have two cases where I do not know how to proceed.

**Case 1** - source XML might contain nodes `Foo1, Foo2, ..., Foo10` (but doesn't have to contain any or all of them). For example,

```
<Foo1>some value</Foo1>
<Foo3>some other value</Foo3>
```

I need to create nodes as follows:

```
<Bar number="1">some value</Bar>
<Bar number="3">some other value</Bar>
```

My XSLT currently is very simple:

```
<xsl:if test="Foo1 != ''">
  <xsl:element name="Bar">
    <xsl:attribute name="number">1</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="Foo1"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

But I obviously need 10 of these code blocks. How can I generalize this?

**Case 2** - In the source XML, I have a couple of nodes of basically the same structure:

```
<Foo>
  <item>
    <Start>2015-06-01</Start>
    <End>9999-12-31</End>
    <Foo>00000008</Foo>
  </item> <!-- 0..n items -->
</Foo>
```

The nodes differ in the name `Foo`, but the rest stays the same. The structure I need to build looks like this:

```
<Bars>
  <Bar From="2015-06-01" To="9999-12-31">
    <Value>00000008</Value>
  </Bar>
</Bars>
```

here's my XSLT attempt, but once again, I need many templates which are very similar to each other:

```
<xsl:element name="Bars>
  <apply-templates select="Foo"/>
</xsl:element>

...

<xsl:template match="Foo/item">
  <xsl:element name="Bar">
    <xsl:attribute name="From">
      <xsl:call-template name="convertDate">
        <xsl:with-param name="theDate" select="Start"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="To">
      <xsl:call-template name="convertDate">
        <xsl:with-param name="theDate" select="End"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:element name="Value">
      <xsl:value-of select="Foo"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

And once more, I have several of the templates, all of which look very similar (i.e., they only differ in the names of the `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Value` elements). Any chance to generalize this, i.e. to provide a single template which can handle all these cases?

Comment: For 1) you should be able to generate the names from a sequence and for 2) you should be able to retrieve the value by xpath "last-child-of-item" (pseudo-xpath). I don't have time for a full answer right now but I'll check back later.

Comment: @Filburt Could you maybe elaborate a bit on your suggestion for 2)? I'm still a bit lost on that one... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Foo')]">
  <Bar number="{translate(local-name(), translate(local-name(), '1234567890', ''), '')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Bar>
</xsl:template>
```

for the first sample.

To convert

```
  <item>
    <Start>2015-06-01</Start>
    <End>9999-12-31</End>
    <Foo>00000008</Foo>
  </item>
```

to

```
  <Bar From="2015-06-01" To="9999-12-31">
    <Value>00000008</Value>
  </Bar>
```

you can use

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <Bar From="{Start}" To="{End}">
    <xsl:value-of select="Foo"/>
  </Bar>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think the second one doesn't address the OP issue: `Foo` is an arbitrary element as I understood the problem, so `<xsl:value-of select="Foo"/>` will not work.

Comment: Admittedly I am not sure on the second problem, whether the statement "The nodes differ in the name Foo" relates to the `Foo` container of the `item` elements or to the `Foo` child.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! I have already implemented the first solution you provided, just had to replace the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` with `<xsl:value-of select="." />` (probably because I have overridden the according built-in template).

Comment: For your second solution, @Filburt is right (sorry for not being precise enough): both `Foo` elements are arbitrary (but always have the same name as far as I can see). Thus, `Foo` referred to both the container *and* the child element.